# Prevent overflow of <p> inside <td> vertically

Tags: html, css, overflow

```css
table {
  width: 660;
  height: 800;
}
table h2 {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
tr {
  max-height: 200px;
}
td {
  border-right: #5c5857 dashed 1px;
  width: 230px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
p {
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#post-thumbnail {
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id='post-thumbnail'>
        <img src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-sI6mm8ZKBss/VPBaKwgV_jI/AAAAAAAAAC0/AIC31jCods8/h120/noimg.png' /></img>
      </span>
      <h2>Blog post title</h2>
      <p>Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy
        Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey
        Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy
        Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey
        Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy
        Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy</p>

    </td>
    <td>
      <span id='post-thumbnail'>
        <img src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-sI6mm8ZKBss/VPBaKwgV_jI/AAAAAAAAAC0/AIC31jCods8/h120/noimg.png' /></img>
      </span>
      <p>Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id='post-thumbnail'>
        <img src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-sI6mm8ZKBss/VPBaKwgV_jI/AAAAAAAAAC0/AIC31jCods8/h120/noimg.png' /></img>
      </span>
      <p>Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy Hey Hey Hey HEy</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to fix the overflow vertically by every means. I tried googling and every other means. I need help to fix the overflow that happens vertically in the td. 
I am trying to create a blog post display style for Blogger. I want the thumbnail to come on top and then a snippet of the blog post. I want 3 such post information to be displayed in a row, but when there's a lot of text, the td just overflows downwards.
I tried many fixes, but each time either the text overflows in any other direction or just displays a single line.

Comment: do you have live demo for this?

Comment: I could set one up. Just hold on.

Comment: Don't use `</img>`. `img` doesn't need closing.

Comment: Could you tell me where I could put up the live html?

Comment: If your table tags don't have an `id` attribute you don't need `#` in your CSS.

Comment: @vistatech codepen.io or jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Rich Actually I had edited it to be placed here. forgot to remove the #. sorry..

Comment: You can see the problem on running the code snippet. It's actually that not matter what I do, the text "Hey Hey ........" keeps overflowing downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `max-height: 250px` on your `p` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
p {
    max-height: 120px; 
}
```

Comment: that doesnt stop the overflow downwards.

Comment: But, still that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: p {
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 150px;
  }

Comment: Maybe you can resize this max-height with jquery calculating the total height of the div that contains it,and reduce then the "p" max-height